# My scanf without va_list (how to base on my printf)

Tags: c

I have to write my own printf and scanf without using va_list, any library functions except for read and write. I implemented printf, I want to base on it when it comes to write scanf, but I don't know how to deal with pointers in this case. Can you tell me how one of the cases should look like?

```
void myprintf (char *format, ...) {

    char *p = (char *) &format + 12 * sizeof(int);
    char *s = format;
    int number;
    char** string;

    for(; *s != '\0'; ++s) {
        if (*s == '%') { 
            switch (*(s+1))
            {
                case 's':
                string = (char**) p;
                write(1, string[0], strlen(string[0]));
                    p += 2 * sizeof(int);
                    ++s;
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    number = *((int *)p);
                    write(1,intToArray(number),strlen(intToArray(number)));
                    p += 2 * sizeof (int);
                    ++s;
                    break;
                default:
                    write(1, "%", 1);
            }       
        } else {  
            write(1, s, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code won't work on e.g. ARM, RISC-V, or IBM Z series.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's irrelevant for his homework, of course...

Answer (score 3):

You can't write *portably* variadic functions without `va_list`.

The `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end` macros translate to compiler magic (e.g. compiler builtin).

Because they are tied to the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) conventions (see also x86 ABI [list](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI), which you might want to follow for your homework).

For example my `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdarg.h` contains:

```
  #define va_start(v,l) __builtin_va_start(v,l)
```